# Explode is deleting the last character from string

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an ecommerce website. I have the following issue which I have came across while I was testing:

1. Updating the order status (In Process, Shipping, Completed and Cancelled) from the admin panel is not working only for 1 product.
2. Explode is deleting the last character when values are retrieved from the database.
3. If there is more than 1 product in the order, order status works completely fine, though the point 2 remains the same.

So for example: Lets say that in my `order (ORD-00001)`,

I have only 1 product (`ABC-000001`). So while exploding, I get the value as (`ABC-00000`).

In my next `order (ORD-00002)`

I have 2 product (`ABC-000001`, `PQR-00005`). So while exploding, I get the value as (`ABC-000001`, `PQR-0000`).

In the second order, the order status works completely fine. But in the first order, it doesn't work at all.

Here's the php button click event:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["btnUpdateOrderStatus"])) {

    $qu = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderCode = '".$_GET["ord"]."'";
    $result = $validate->Query($qu);
    if (!$result) {
        echo $validate->Error();
        exit();
    }
    while ($rowp = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
        $p = explode(', ', $rowp["ProdCode"]);

        foreach ($_POST["updateOrderPerProductStatus"] as $key => $value) {
            //echo $key;
            for ($i=0; $i < count($p); $i++) { 
                if( $p[$i] == $key) {
                    $querToUpdateOrderStatus = "UPDATE orders SET OrderStatus = '".implode(', ',$_POST["updateOrderPerProductStatus"])."' WHERE OrderCode = '".$_GET["ord"]."' ";

                    if ($validate->Query($querToUpdateOrderStatus)) {
                        header("Location: http://www.example.com/nbs/Administrators/Orders/Update.php?ord=".$_SESSION["ord"]."&id=".$_SESSION["id"]);
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        echo $validate->Error();
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Here's the code that I have used:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT o.*, com.* FROM orders o, commission com WHERE o.OrderCode = '".$ord."'";

$validate->Query($query);

if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
    while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {

        $products = explode(',', $row['ProdCode']); // <-- error line
        $qnty = explode(', ', $row['Quantity']);
        $orderStats = explode(', ', $row["OrderStatus"]);
        $productsWithQunty = array_combine($products, $qnty);

        echo '
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Order Code: </td>
            <td style="width: 50%">'.$row["OrderCode"].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Order Date: </td>
            <td style="width: 50%">'.$row["OrderDate"].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Order Status: </td>
            <td style="width: 50%">'.$row["OrderStatus"].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Order Modified: </td>
            <td style="width: 50%">'.$row["OrderModified"].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Order Payable: </td>
            <td style="width: 50%">'.number_format($row["PayableAmount"], 2).'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Products: </td>
            <td style="width: 50%">';
            foreach ($productsWithQunty as $key => $value) {
                echo $key . ":" . $value;
            }
            echo '</td>
        </tr>';
        $arrProductStatus = array_combine($products, $orderStats);
        ?>
        <form action="Update.php?ord=<?php echo $ord; ?>" method="POST">
            <?php
            foreach ($arrProductStatus as $key => $value) {
                echo '
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%">'.$key.'</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%">                                 
                        <select name="updateOrderPerProductStatus['.$key.']">
                            <option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.' -- selected</option>
                            <option value="In Process">In Process</option>
                            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                            <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                            <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" name="btnUpdateOrderStatus" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT 1:**

The product array:
For `order (ORD-00001)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC-000001
)
```

For `order (ORD-00002)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC-000001
    [1] => PQR-00005
)
```

**EDIT 2:**

After RickJames Comment, here's what I get from the actual database.

Code:

```
echo $row["ProdCode"];
$products = explode(', ', $row['ProdCode']);
print_r($products);
```

Result for the above code:

```
DC-0001-0002, PK-0002-000 // The actual product code coming from DB

Array ( [0] => DC-0001-0002 [1] => PK-0002-000 )
```

And in the database I have:

```
OrderCode    CustomerId    ProductCode
ORD-000002       1      DC-0001-0002, PK-0002-0004
```

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just specify in which line that error is comming

Comment: Also can you show $row['ProdCode'] array

Comment: I am still confused which one is $row['ProdCode']. Please write it there also

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Where should I write ??

Comment: @Gumbo I have already escaped the string and then passing it to the query.

Comment: @user3514160 why you don't just call $validate $db instead; it's probably no wonder you don't understand your own code while one cannot read it.

Comment: Please add echo (or print_r) before and after the explode.  I want to see what is being exploded and the incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = explode(',', $row['ProdCode']); // <-- error line
```

Use white space after (,) needle.

```
$products = explode(', ', $row['ProdCode']);
```

Use this code

Comment: One more thing, while answering, please format the code so that it looks nice and readable.

Comment: then you are making some silly mistake because at my hand it is working perfectly. Can you tell me at which step that problem occur.

Answer (score 0):

In **EDIT 2** you indicate that the value of `$row["ProdCode"]` actually lacks a `4` at the end.  Therefore, `explode(...)` isn't the issue.  If `$row["ProdCode"]` is really only `"DC-0001-0002, PK-0002-000"` as you indicate then the issue seems to lie in `$validate->FetchAllDatas()` where `$row` gets set.

Comment: Then what could be the issue, according to you ?

Comment: But I have used `$validate->FetchAllDatas()` to many places in my application. I couldn't find any kind of issue. It is at this place only that I have the issue. Rest all is working fine.